# Plotting Standard Deviation for next month

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I am getting "Script could not be translated from: |B|startDate := timestamp(year, month" for the below code.  But toggle box is not telling line of code.  Update in pinescript?  Can anyone guide where the error is in the code and how to correct it?

Code is for calculating standard deviation values to be plotted on next month.  Period starts on day after last Thursday of previous month and ends on last Thursday of current month.  Eg. for plotting February std dev., std dev will be for the period - 30/12/2022 and 26/1/2023.  If 26th is holiday then 25th as last date.

```
study("Standard Deviation of Month on Next Month", overlay=true)

// Define the start and end dates of the current month     
startDate = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth(timestamp(year, month, 1)) + 5 - weekofyear(timestamp(year, month, 1)))     
endDate = timestamp(year,month, dayofmonth(timestamp(year, month, 1)) + 5 - weekofyear(timestamp(year, month, 1)) + daysinmonth(year, month) - 1)
 
// Calculate the standard deviation of the close price for the current month     
stddev = stdev(close, startDate, endDate)

// Define the start and end dates of the next month     
nextStartDate := timestamp(year, month + 1, dayofmonth(timestamp(year, month + 1, 1)) + 5 - weekofyear(timestamp(year, month + 1, 1)))     
nextEndDate :=timestamp(year, month + 1, dayofmonth(timestamp(year, month + 1, 1)) + 5 - weekofyear(timestamp(year, month + 1, 1)) + daysinmonth(year,month + 1) - 1)

// Plot the standard deviation on the next month  
plot(stddev,nextStartDate, nextEndDate, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Standard Deviation")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is missing the version declaration.

Add your version at the top of your script then try compiling again.

It looks like it is v4, so you can use `//@version=4`.

Comment: I did that, even tried v5.  Error showing is this - Could not find function or function reference 'daysinmonth'  So far it is only this one.  I don't know if more will come out once this is corrected.

Comment: Yes, because there is no `daysinmonth` function in `pinescript`. More will probably come as this is chatGPT generated code.

Comment: Yes this is from there.  What i could collate from google was not working either.  Can you guide how I can rectify this?